# Hyphenation in Android

Tags: android, textview, word-wrap, hyphenation

As part of internationalizing an Android application I have come across the need to dynamically word wrap or hyphenate at the right position.

All my strings are externalized in strings.xml files but I have not found any documentation about hyphenation in Android.

I would like to be able to suggest hyphenation positions similar to how I can do it in LaTeX:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphenation_algorithm

But I have not found any indication if this is possible. Is there anything in the framework I have missed? What are other people doing e.g. with Japanese strings that have no obvious position to break up a sentence? Do you just add spaces at the correct positions?

I could dynamically size the font to fit into certain layouts but for longer messages that go across multiple lines that won't work. What to do?

Comment: Does android respect the soft-hyphen character? (U+00AD)

Comment: I've had similar problems with Korean and other langauges where single words are huge. So interested in an answer. One question might be is it acceptable to break up the word in the first place?

Comment: @anon .. yeah soft hyphen character might be interesting. I will check that out.

Comment: @Emile well .. I dont know enough about Japanese or Korean but it would certainly be weird to break up the word the first place in other languages.. but it would be good to know.

Comment: Latex provided a way to suggest how to separate words. I really don't remember the name, but I would search for how to do it in Latex and check if it works on android.

Comment: That does not work. Maybe the soft hyphen works. Still have to try that.

Comment: @Manfred Moser: any success with the soft hyphen?

Comment: No I did not have any reproducible luck with that.

Comment: Soft hyphen works in Android 4.4, does not work in 4.2. I would like to know whether it works in 4.3, that's what I hoped to find out on this page.

Comment: @arnt See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454911/hyphenation-in-android/35195787#35195787). Android 4.3 seems to support it at least on SAMSUNG devices.

Comment: SDK 17: neither ­­­­\u00AD nor \u200B work. SDK 19: \u200B breaks a word without a hyphen character. SDK 24 - ­­­­\u00AD correct hyphenation, \u200B breaks a word without a hyphen character.

Comment: Does &shy; from html will work on Android?

Answer (score 14):

Its a new thing from Android 6 Marshmellow.

Try adding this to your TextView xml

```
android:hyphenationFrequency="none"
```

Comment: In Android Q up it's set to "none" per default. Earlier it wasn't the case.

Comment: I want to add setHyphenationFrequency(int)

Comment: hyphenation is turned "off" by default from Android Q to increase performance, If you need it, you need to turn it on. https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/07/whats-new-for-text-in-android-q.html

Answer (score 7):

Management of line breaks can be a hassle.  The best option is to use UTF line-break modifier control characters since android supports full UTF

I know someone mentioned "soft-hyphen", but there are quite a few more.

You can also use the "Zero Width Space" between words on languages that lack spaces so you don't have to rely on dictionary interpretation. You can also use this as a soft-hyphen in languages that allow breaking of certain words over lines at certain points.

When using a compound word that you don't want broken, but you want the Text To Speech system to recognize it properly you should use "Word Separator" character.  Don't use "Zero Width Non Breaking Space" as that has been deprecated due to it's use as BOM.

Finally, if you want a space but don't want a line break, use a simple non-breaking space.

Comment: Successfully used \u200b for this in xml resource file with strings

Comment: Soft Hyphens are an extremely useful tool and worked in Android targeting API 21  - \u00AD https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen

Comment: Like any platform the availability of the common "&" shortcuts used in HTML, depend on where they are used in the application.   Some widgets run their text through a parser that handles them, some don't.  If you use Internationalization string table functions to handle strings (which you absolutely should) you can use UTF.

Answer (score 7):

[Soft hyphen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen) worked on a Samsung Galaxy device starting with Android 4.3.

```
<!-- key combination to enter soft hyphen: [Alt Gr]+[-] or [Alt]+240 on German PC, see https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weiches_Trennzeichen#Darstellung_auf_Computersystemen -->
<string name="no_connection">Nicht ver-bund-en</string>
```

[image]

Since my use case was pretty narrow, I just used one soft hyphen in the word "verbunden". The Unicode  \u00ad had no effect.

Comment: I did not follow [duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/verbunden) to devide the word correctly. ;)

Comment: Maybe you should use \u00AD (capital letters on 2 last position)... for me it works perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The following library supports hyphenation. It does all types of text alignment (left/right/center/justified) and hyphenation for you. Not all languages have been added but can be added as necessary. This library uses **NO WEBVIEWS** and **SUPPORTS SPANNABLES** and allows for **LONG TEXT**.

**LIBRARY**: https://github.com/bluejamesbond/TextJustify-Android

**ANDROID**: 2.2 to 5.X

**SETUP**

```
DocumentView documentView = addDocumentView(new StringBuilder("Your long text content"), DocumentView.PLAIN_TEXT);
documentView.getDocumentLayoutParams().setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.JUSTIFIED);
documentView.getDocumentLayoutParams().setHyphenator(new Hyphenator(HyphenPattern.PT));
documentView.getDocumentLayoutParams().setHyphenated(true);
```

Comment: How we can set this property in a textView?. Can you please modify this.

Answer (score 3):

The question is old but just found best solution for me:

I have to say i'm programming in Xamarin, so the code is in C# but should not be a problem to port into java.

I used the NHyphenator Logic (https://github.com/alkozko/NHyphenator) for Inserting SoftHyphens(UTF8 Symbol - 0x00AD) so the Textview do hyphenation at the right place.

To get Hyphenation for other languages i used the openoffice Dictionaries.
e.g. i had to get Hyphenation for german-swiss language

http://extensions.openoffice.org/en/search?f[0]=field_project_tags%3A157
1. Download the extension
2. Unzip it with winrar or something else
3. Copy the hyph_xx_xx/hyph_xx_xx.dic file 
4. Add new Language to the Hyphenator class

NHyphernator resource files are declared as:
hyph-xx-xx.pat.txt  --> content of the dic file without comments
hyph-xx-xx.hyp.txt  --> file which contains word-exceptions where the logic for hyphening does not give correct results

If anyone wants the portable Library for Xamarin just tell, i can upload it.

**EDIT:**

The breakstrategy should be set to Balanced in TExtview. API Level > 23, else don't use breakstrategy.

**EDIT:**

Here's the mono/xamarin code:
https://github.com/sma84/NHyphenator-Mono

Comment: Is it possible to upload the portable library for Xamarin?

Comment: just uploaded it. en_gb, en_us, rus and de_ch is added right now. Added in the readme how to add a new language.  https://github.com/sma84/NHyphenator-Mono

Answer (score -3):

[setEllipsize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setEllipsize%28android.text.TextUtils.TruncateAt%29) might be of help, if [this](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg44652.html) error is yet fixed.

Comment: While that helps in some cases I really want the whole text to be visible, but just be wrapped/hyphenated in the right place..

Comment: I haven't used ellipsizing yet, but I thought it shows the whole text. No clue about the hyphenating in the wanted place though.