# Word has not enough space in single line

Tags: android, textview, hyphenation

I have an TextView with a big fontsize and if I have a long word only the last char is put into the next line. For example :

Zusammenarbei

t

Now I would like to format the text to look like this:

Zusammenarb -

t

Is there a possibility to achive this?

Comment: You should look into hyphenation, there is more information in this SO link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454911/hyphenation-in-android

Answer (score 1):

I guess better than doing Hyphenation, you can do something better.Consider the following image.

[image]

I guess green one will be much suitable for your need. Just declare your `textview` as follows:

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/yourUniqueID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:ellipsize="end"  <!--THIS WILL DO FOR YOU-->
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="test"/>
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer but the textview has multiple lines and this one isnt the last one so i can't use this strategy

Comment: Reduce the text size to some extent then

Answer (score 1):

Look at the break strategy of the [TextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:breakStrategy)

`android:breakStrategy="high_quality"`

```
constant      value               description
high_quality    1   Line breaking uses high-quality strategy, including hyphenation.
```