# How to remove dash in long string textview android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, textview

I have a textview to show a result from a process, but when the result too long (more than my textview width), it will automatically append a dash like in blue circle (in picture). How to remove it without make it scrollable, just remove the dash?

[image]

Comment: You can replace dash with blank space using replace function,like      String str="your result";      str=str.replace("-","");

Comment: Or use `textView.setText(editText.getText().toString().replace("-",""));`

Comment: No, not from the code I think. My code literally be like textView.setText("HereIsMyLongStringWithoutSpace"). So the problem is on the layout or XML (maybe).

Comment: Share xml and java code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hyphenation in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454911/hyphenation-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using api 23 or above , you can use `android:breakStrategy` and as value [BREAK_STRATEGY_SIMPLE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Layout.html#BREAK_STRATEGY_SIMPLE).

Answer (score 1):

This might not be proper solution of your problem but it will help you to achieve this.
Use EditTextView instead of TextView and set `android:focusableInTouchMode="false",android:focusable="false"` ,then EditTextView will work like TextView and it will not show dash(-) symble

Answer (score 1):

Add this on your TextView android:hyphenationFrequency="none", this will remove the hyphen

Answer (score 0):

It is now possible with soft hyphen -> use **\u00AD** in strings, e.g.:

`<string name="einzelfahrt_name">Einzelfahrrad\u00ADkarte</string>`

Also, in your TextView, you have to add:

```
 android:hyphenationFrequency="full"
```